# how can I run localhost? (NODE.JS)

Tags: node.js

For some reason, my code is not working. what am I doing wrong?

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(req.url === '/') {
        res.write('hello world!');
        res.end;
    }
});
server.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port 8000');
```

Comment: Can you explain what does "not working" means and what do you do to run the code?

Comment: I am trying to run localhost on my pc. I type 'node app.js'( the name of my js file) into Git Bash and head to my browser to check 'localhost:8000'. but it's not loading

Comment: Does your server bind to IPv6 or IPv4? `localhost` is by default IPv4, perhaps your node.js app does not create a network socket with IPv4, try to add `127.0.0.1` as second argument to `server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1");` and: you have to write `res.end()` in your request handler, "end" is a function.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment you mention that you use git bash, I am not sure if this is a standard bash or some wrapped bash version that could potentially misbehave.

But also you have an error in the code. You do not call `res.end()`.

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(req.url === '/') {
        res.write('hello world!');
        res.end(); // HERE replaced res.end; with res.end(); as you do not call the method
    }
});
server.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port 8000');
```

Comment: "Git Bash for Windows" is just bash compiled with MSYS